# Angular Template to work with but without the headache of UI design

Tags: angular, angular-material, vmware-clarity, nebular, ng-zorro-antd

I've looked for templates, components, libraries...etc to work with and I've bean comparing but my experience is too little to anticipate the front-end future complexities that might face me as challenges so I'm looking for the right decision now, or the most close to. Hoping by answering the following questions.

Objective: To work with full web application and its business logic headache away from other concerns such as CSS theming, libraries compatibility, JavaScript challenges, responsiveness, RTL..etc. Instead stability, security, business(functionality)...etc of the app is my main concern.

Considerations:

- Angular is my to go framework to use for presentation and navigation of the web app
- Latest version should be always be in mind for proper support and stability as well as using new features. So breaking changes is headache enough added for this point.
- So far libraries found in mind are PrimeNG, BootStrap (for grid system), Nebular & Angular-Material.
- RTL and layout easiness of usage is really important.

Questions:

- What is to use/learn to start working with but has the least requirement and details to pay attention to ? Nebular for example got 4 themes out of the box and no need to do CSS/SCSS work if ngx-admin used so this lets me really focus on the functionality rather than the look.
- What is the best and more flexible to use as grid system for responsiveness ? BootStrap grid system been there for too long and it's really easy to use but if I go for angular material then that would be additional work rather than just sticking with Angular-Material responsiveness support which I don't know anything about yet.
- ngx-admin like apps would be straightforward to do but nebular is kinda restrictive compared to angular material and less supported, could be angular material be that easy/straightforward to use without caring about css as such ?
- **In nebular,** rounding your html with `nb-layout` really takes care of theming & rtl. Any alternative to that in PrimeNG, Angular-Material or others ?

Comment: This is multiple questions and not a single question, so that's likely a reason why no one bothers to parse and answer what you trying to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is to use/learn to start working with but has the least requirement and details to pay attention to ? Nebular for example got 4 themes out of the box and no need to do CSS/SCSS work if ngx-admin used so this lets me really focus on the functionality rather than the look.

Whatever got a ready-to-go template. This would be your quickest option to get started in no time. [ngx-admin](https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin) based on nebular is great for you in this manner. Also [ng-alain](https://github.com/ng-alain/ng-alain) is another option. Pick a strong supported template which better be open source imho would suit your request.

> What is the best and more flexible to use as grid system for responsiveness ? BootStrap grid system been there for too long and it's really easy to use but if I go for angular material then that would be additional work rather than just sticking with Angular-Material responsiveness support which I don't know anything about yet.

No right or wrong answers here. Use whatever suits you. But stick with one solution and don't get confused.

> ngx-admin like apps would be straightforward to do but nebular is kinda restrictive compared to angular material and less supported, could be angular material be that easy/straightforward to use without caring about css as such ?

You're comparing a template showcase to framework implantation of a design. It's not possible nor fair to do so. Pick a template like [Material Dashboard](https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-dashboard-angular2) and compare it to whatever other and see what suits you better. There are many templates built on raw angular material

> In nebular, rounding your html with nb-layout really takes care of theming & rtl. Any alternative to that in PrimeNG, Angular-Material or others ?

Yes layout is supported in Angular Material but you will have to create unified solution to theming, direction...etc on your own. There are different approaches to that. However, it's ready out of the box exists in [NG-ZORRO](https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd) & [Clarity](https://github.com/vmware/clarity) for example. You'll have to search and ask about available features in whatever you'd use.

There is no single one is better here but you will have to balance your needs against what you'll work to get and implement on your own.